# How to view Spring MVC request mapping exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, request-mapping

When I deployed a Spring MVC application into Tomcat and startup the Tomcat instance, the log prints out various exception similar to the one below:

```
INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:197 - Mapped "{[/user/forgotPassword],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" 
onto public java.util.Map net.tangs.three6five.web.controller.UserController.forgotPassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
```

My question is how can I view what the actual exception is with the mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Exception. You controller method is mapped successfully. It just prints the method signature.

```
java.util.Map net.tangs.three6five.web.controller.UserController.forgotPassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
```